# How to align grouping text property of Asp panel

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp:Panel where Grouping text is equal to "string".Now this string comes on the left hand side on the upper half of panel border.I want this grouping text to come in the center as in a title of the panel.How can we do this

Comment: this is not a customer requirement.I'm learning asp.net and just want to see if grouping text can be aligned in the center

Comment: @Paul This site is a resource for developers to OBTAIN answers, so please keep your criticisms to yourself unless you have something more constructive to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move it to the right using css. Although I don't know of a way to have it automatically centered.

Target it by using `legend {margin-left:<px>;}`

Comment: Beautiful works...I was trying using position absolute.That too does the job.Thanks

Comment: margin: 0 auto doesn't work, that was the first property I tested. But if, in the future you use margin: 0 auto, you need to define a width as well.